# Find the no of principal solution of the equation $\sin x-\sin3x+\sin5x=\cos x-\cos3x+\cos5x$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the no of principal solution of the equation $\sin x-\sin3x+\sin5x=\cos x-\cos3x+\cos5x$

My attempt is as follows:-

$$\sin x-\sin3x+\sin5x=\cos x-\cos3x+\cos5x$$
$$2\sin3x\cos2x-\sin3x=2\cos3x\cos2x-\cos3x$$
$$\sin3x(2\cos2x-1)=\cos3x(2\cos2x-1)$$
$$(2\cos2x-1)(\sin3x-\cos3x)=0$$
$$\cos2x=\cos\dfrac{\pi}{3} \text { or } \tan3x=0$$
$$2x=2n\pi\pm\dfrac{\pi}{3} \text { or } 3x=n\pi$$
$$x=n\pi\pm\dfrac{\pi}{6} \text { or } x=\dfrac{n\pi}{3}$$

So Principal solutions will be ${0,\dfrac{\pi}{3},\dfrac{2\pi}{3},\pi,\dfrac{4\pi}{3},\dfrac{5\pi}{3},2\pi,\dfrac{\pi}{6},\dfrac{5\pi}{6},\dfrac{7\pi}{6},\dfrac{11\pi}{6}}$

So my answer is $11$ but actual answer is $10$. I tried a lot to find the mistake but didn't know which angle they are excluding and why.

Surprisingly at $x=0,\dfrac{\pi}{3}$, original equation is not getting satisfied $\left(\text { I didn't check for other angles }\right)$.

At $x=0$

$$\sin0-\sin0+\sin0=\cos0-\cos0+\cos0$$
$$0=1 \left(\text{ contradictory }\right)$$

At $x=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$
$$\sin\dfrac{\pi}{3}-\sin\pi+\sin\dfrac{5\pi}{3}=\cos\dfrac{\pi}{3}-\cos\pi+\cos\dfrac{5\pi}{3}$$
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-0-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}-\left(-1\right)+\dfrac{1}{2}$$
$$0=2 \left(\text { contradictory }\right)$$

I don't understand why this is happening?

Comment: If sin(3x) - cos(3x) = 0, then tan(3x) = 1 instead of 0 as you assume.

Answer (score 2):

From here

$$(2\cos2x-1)(\sin3x-\cos3x)=0$$

we have

$$\cos2x=\frac12 =\cos\frac \pi 3 \iff 2x=\frac \pi 3+2k\pi \quad \lor \quad 2x=-\frac \pi 3+2k\pi$$

$$\iff x=\frac \pi 6+k\pi \quad \lor \quad x=-\frac \pi 6+k\pi$$

and

$$\sin3x-\cos3x=0 \iff \tan (3x)=1 \iff 3x= \frac\pi 4+k\pi \iff x=\frac{\pi} {12}+k\frac \pi 3$$

therefore the solutions are: $\frac \pi 6$, $\frac {7\pi} 6$, $\frac {5\pi} 6$, $\frac {11\pi} 6$, $\frac {\pi} {12}$, $\frac {5\pi} {12}$, $\frac {9\pi} {12}$, $\frac {13\pi} {12}$, $\frac {17\pi} {12}$, $\frac {21\pi} {12}$.

Comment: thanks, so stupid of me

Comment: There are three more solutions: $13\pi/12$, $17\pi/12$ and $21\pi/12$.

Comment: @M.Wind Opsss yes of course I stopped to $\pi$! Thanks I fix that.